# Deny visitors with invalid IP address in PHP

Tags: php, security, ip

I would like to deny the access to my portal for visitors with invalid IP address. Is it a good solution?

```
   $ipaddress = '';
   if (getenv('HTTP_CLIENT_IP'))
       $ipaddress = getenv('HTTP_CLIENT_IP');
   else if(getenv('HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'))
       $ipaddress = getenv('HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR');
   else if(getenv('HTTP_X_FORWARDED'))
       $ipaddress = getenv('HTTP_X_FORWARDED');
   else if(getenv('HTTP_FORWARDED_FOR'))
       $ipaddress = getenv('HTTP_FORWARDED_FOR');
   else if(getenv('HTTP_FORWARDED'))
       $ipaddress = getenv('HTTP_FORWARDED');
   else if(getenv('REMOTE_ADDR'))
       $ipaddress = getenv('REMOTE_ADDR');
   else
       $ipaddress = '';

   if ( filter_var ($ipaddress, FILTER_VALIDATE_IP) == false)
   {
      $ipaddress = '';
   }

   if ($ipaddress == '')
   {
      die ();
   }
```

Thanks!

Comment: If they have an invalid IP address they probably aren't going to get the response back. Also if I were to take the time to spoof an IP I'd use one that would validate.

Comment: Somebody with an 'invalid IP' address will not be able to use the internet, you need a valid IP address. Perhaps you should define more precisely what you mean by 'invalid'?

Comment: This past article seem to answer your question.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7939905/how-to-detect-the-actual-ip-address-of-visitors?rq=1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**I think you wanted to allow only visitors with real IP Address not spoof?**

Your code below will allow spoof IP Address on your website, however, i fixed it and provided a very short function
that will do what you are looking for.

```
<?php
$ipaddress = '';
   if (getenv('HTTP_CLIENT_IP'))
       $ipaddress = getenv('HTTP_CLIENT_IP');
   else if(getenv('HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'))
       $ipaddress = getenv('HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR');
   else if(getenv('HTTP_X_FORWARDED'))
       $ipaddress = getenv('HTTP_X_FORWARDED');
   else if(getenv('HTTP_FORWARDED_FOR'))
       $ipaddress = getenv('HTTP_FORWARDED_FOR');
   else if(getenv('HTTP_FORWARDED'))
       $ipaddress = getenv('HTTP_FORWARDED');
   else if(getenv('REMOTE_ADDR'))
       $ipaddress = getenv('REMOTE_ADDR');
   else
       $ipaddress = '';

   if ( filter_var ($ipaddress, FILTER_VALIDATE_IP) == false)
   {
      $ipaddress = '';
      die();
   }

   /**  You don't want this here;
        kill the script once IP Validation return false.
   if ($ipaddress == '')
   {
      die ();
   }
   */
```

##Use this function below;

```
   function checkIPAddress()
   {
      // Get IP Address using $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
      $ipaddress = ($_SERVER('REMOTE_ADDR')) ? $_SERVER('REMOTE_ADDR') : '';

       if ( filter_var ($ipaddress, FILTER_VALIDATE_IP) == false)
       {
          $ipaddress = '';
          die();
       }
   }
```

Allow `HTTP_X_FORWARDED` is a bad habit.  Use it when you are doing proxy server, load balancing etc.